# Share 3 Internet Connections with one router

Tags: networking, router

I have 3 internet connections with three ADSL modems (three modems doesn't have wifi). I own a router which has 4 Lan ports and 1 Wan port. Now I want to connect the three ethernet cables (of the three modems) to the lan port of the router and then use the wifi hotspot from the router (because the router has wifi antenna). Is it possible to do this or will these connections clash with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. It will only work if you have 3 ADSL ports.
http://www.ehow.com/facts_6292275_dsl-vs_-ethernet.html

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is not quite correct.

Actually you may be able to connect all 3 it if the router with the wifi has an ethernet WAN port not just and ADSL port. Many do now have that because a lot of high-speed broadband is now presented via a residential gateway or pure ADSL modem. My Billion 7800N does for example.

In that case, you would connect the 3 outer LAN connections to a switch and the inner router's WAN port to the same switch.

However, it wouldn't do what I think you expect. The problem is that the inner router needs to know where to route internal traffic. It almost certainly will not have the capability to multi-host. In other words,  it will only have the ability to remember 1 route to the internet - over one of the 3 connections. There are ways to do this but you would either need an enterprise level router or a more fully featured Linux server acting as a router.